# Looking for a easy enough way to manage virtual machine accounts connecting to MS SQL 2008R2

Tags: sql-server, virtual, accounts

Our solution stack consists of multiple services, each of which can be run on individual host machines. For a variety of reasons, the services are hosted as a windows service running under a virtual account. Many of these services need to connect to a MS SQL 2008R2 instance running on a remote host. Each of the host machines running the services thus need to  added to the MS SQL2008R2 instances as logins. e.g if our services are running on hostnames machine1, machine2...machinen,  machine accounts  machine1$, machine2$... machinen$ need to be added to MS SQL as logins. I thought I could simplify this by adding each host machine to a machine group on the domain and add the machine group as a login on the MS SQL instance. This did not work. Am I  missing some steps ? OR am I forever condemned to add each individual machine accounts to MS SQL instance ? I know that I can run the windows services under a domain user (or maybe have the services impersonate a domain user if possible) and add the domain user to the MS SQL instance but I do not want to try this approach as the password for the domain user now needs to be managed.
Any help appreciated

Comment: What the heck is a "virtual account"???

Comment: You can use a group. I would investigate why that wasn't working for you.

Answer (score 0):

Once the server and workstation were rebooted, it worked. Now just having the security group on MS SQL and no individual machine account on MS SQL gets our solution stack up and running. Thank you SQLChao for keeping me on track.